# Python library PIL, loaded image is blue

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-imaging-library, pyside

Hi I have a litte problem with my program, but I don't understand what is wrong. Bug appear when I try open a image, then the image appear in box under, but colour's are wrong, red/yellow/orange colour change to blue. Sorry for my English, just look on screen's under.

My main code:

http://pastebin.com/9Wq9sUDb

Image after load from program:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7q26.png

Orginal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztm80.jpg

Anybody know what is wrong ?

Comment: It looks like the red and blue pixels are getting flipped somewhere. Looking at the code, I can't tell where.

Comment: Can you make this a more concise question? The code with the error in it is too long to search for a mistake. Try to isolate the problem to a single method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly I haven't used QT (I don't even have it installed, so I can't test), but it seems to me that this is where your problem lies:

```
my_image.data = data = img.convert('RGBA').tobytes('raw', 'RGBA')
my_image.qt = img_qt = QImage(data, img.size[0], img.size[1], QImage.Format_ARGB32)
```

You're storing the image in RGBA format and loading it in ARGB format. Naturally, the colors are going to get swapped.

However, since it seems from the screenshots that just blue and red is being swapped, I'm guessing there's also some endian mismatch in there, so that you effectively load it in BGRA format. PIL gives you the bytes in the order specified -- R, G, B, A -- so QT probably loads each pixel as a little-endian word. Try `.tobytes('raw', 'BGRA')` instead.

Comment: Ok mate, It work :) Very thanks, I missed that small detail.

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation for `RGBA` in PIL and for [`Format_ARGB32`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#Format-enum) in Qt is different.

PIL stores a pixel `(r, g, b, a)` as bytes in the form of `b'rrggbbaa'`* (therefore RGBA), which would correspond to a 32-bit Integer of `0xaabbggrr`*.

Qt uses a 32 bit Integer `0xaarrggbb` (therefore ARGB), which converted to bytes would be `b'bbggrraa'`

So you can see that in the binary representation the bytes for red and blue are swapped. To correctly convert a PIL image to a QImage, you should use the `toqimage()` function from the [`PIL.ImageQt`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageQt.py) module.

---

*where rr, gg, bb and aa stand for the hex-representation of the values for r, g, b, a